# Convert the following code to a oneliner

Tags: python, lambda

I need to turn this code to one line code, without using yield, but it could involve the use of lambda.

f is a function an x0 is the first given number to enter the function

```
def give_value(f,x0):
    yield x0
    fx = x0
    while True:
        yield f(fx)
        fx = f(fx)
```

any ideas?

Comment: This will _always_ yield `x0`. The rest of your code won't even be touched. Are you sure this is your function? I mean try the following code, it will go into an infinite [loop](https://dpaste.de/O2H6)

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Are you sure you know what `yield` does?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, the code runs and gets to the inner yield inside the "while" block

Comment: @user2357112 Why yes.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac It is an infinite generator. Why do you claim it only yields `x0`?

Comment: @MatanB Why do you need to turn it into one line?